# I am trying to filter some key values and store it in another object using _.omit But it seems it is not working properly

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

_.pick is working fine but not omit.

```
var student = {
   "student_name" : "Ankit Kaushik",
    "student_email": "ankit@studysolo.com",
    "student_school" : "DPS"};

var student_details = _.omit(student, ['student_email','student_school']);
```

student_details is showing all the three key-value pairs.

Comment: Seems to work just fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/wott2y2L/

Comment: Damn.Not on my system.

Comment: It works just fine..